# Science fiction influences on the Radiohead album "OK Computer"

Tags: kurt-vonnegut, cats-cradle, radiohead

Radiohead have given many interviews over the years about the recording of the album *OK Computer*, the title of which was inspired by (if I recall correctly) the BBC TV version of the *Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy* in which the character of Zaphod Beeblebrox is heard to say "Ok Computer..." The song "Paranoid Android" is another science fiction reference point.

I once read an interview in which Thom Yorke talked about books he had read and how they influenced other songs. I no longer have that magazine so cannot reference the article, I believe it would have been either *Q Magazine* or *MOJO*, published in the UK. I recall mention of Kurt Vonnegut and believe there was discussion of the novel *Cat's Cradle*. I would like to know if this was an influence on a specific song and if so in what way. If anyone knows or can point me to a quote or interview with the band where this is discussed I would be grateful.

Comment: Paranoid Android isn't just another reference point, it's another reference point to HHGTTG

Comment: @NKCampbell, yes I meant that! It's a very clumsy sentence l apologize!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found [two](https://citizeninsane.eu/music/bends/nicedream.html) [sites](http://www.radiohead.fr/nice-dream/) that provide the same quote from *MOJO* issue 117, August 2003:

> Following his return to his basement flat in Oxford, one evening saw Yorke falling into "a sort of drunken coma and singing a song which became '[Nice Dream]'. That song refers to a story by Kurt Vonnegut where this crystal's been found that turns all water completely solid and someone drops it into the sea. If you want to kill yourself you just put your finger into the water."

The former site (citizeninsane.eu) is cited as a *source* for the *MOJO* article by [this book about Radiohead](https://books.google.ca/books?id=eh24DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT116&lpg=PT116&dq=MOJO+Issue+117+/+August+2003&source=bl&ots=ukinx0beZW&sig=ACfU3U1rQxJB9zzFocc9br-1oFHatFd61w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjxyvaZwKrzAhVsMlkFHbQvC_YQ6AF6BAgiEAI#v=snippet&q=MOJO%20&f=false) though the given link is now dead, and the [page has moved here](https://citizeninsane.eu/media/uk/mojo/06/pt_2003-08_mojo.htm).  If we accept this as an accurate copy, there isn't any more about Vonnegut.

Comment: many thanks for this. Really nice to know which song it inspired after all these years.